# How to play my function on animate cc?

Tags: javascript, animation, createjs, animate-cc

I created a function:

```
function playFirework() {
createjs.Tween.get(this.red_firework, { loop: false })
.to({ y: 100 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
}
```

this makes a firework move to up to y=100 on the canvas. When I remove the function and just leave the body, it plays by itself. I tried calling it

```
playFirework();
```

or

```
this.playFirework();
```

but it doesn't seem to play.

Any ideas why?

Comment: There are no telepaths in here. Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: This is the error I get: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._target[h]')

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. Your function is defined anonymously, so its only available in the scope of that frame. When it is called, `this` is global, so `this.red_firework` is undefined.

An easy solution is to just define the function on `this`.

```
this.playFirework = function() {
    createjs.Tween.get(this.red_firework, { loop: false })
      .to({ y: 100 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
}
```

This will make the scope correct if you call it using `this.playFirework()`.

You can also leave the function as-is, but bind the call to `this`.

```
playFirework.call(this);
```

Hope that helps!